# Show data rows by common column name in WordPress database custom table query

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I need to group foreach row by common league name. This is WordPress database custom table query. While in simple MySql query I get it working but through WP db query, I don't know. Here is what i need.
Here you see we can group by league name "Italy Series A" and "England Premier League".

**Current data:**

League Name | 
Event Name

**Italy Serie A**

Cagliari - Genoa

---

**England Premier League**

Southampton - Bournemouth

---

**England Premier League**

Leicester - Tottenham

---

**England Premier League**

Burnley - Norwich

<------------------ XXX -----------!>

I need this to sort as this. All event names under the single common league name as there is no point of repeating the league name.

**Data I need to be displayed like this:**

League Name | 
Event Name

**Italy Serie A**

Cagliari - Genoa

---

**England Premier League**

Southampton - Bournemouth

Leicester - Tottenham

Burnley - Norwich

<------------------ XXX -----------!>

This one is the sample query.

```
$pre = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `prematch` WHERE sport_id =1 ORDER BY timer");
                 $league_name = 0;
                  foreach ($pre as $event) {
                        $l_name = $event->league_name;
                        $event_name = $event->event_name;                       

                        if($league_name != $l_name){
                        $leg_name = $event->league_name;
                        }

                         echo $leg_name;
                         echo $event_name
```

Help or suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The method `get_results` has a second parameter:

wpdb::get_results( string $query = null, **string $output = OBJECT** )

Make use of it and pass **ARRAY_A**, then `get_results` will return an array instead of an object:

```
$pre = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `prematch` WHERE sport_id =1 ORDER BY timer", ARRAY_A);
```

Then handle the array:

```
$ligues_events = array();

foreach ($pre as $key => $item) {
   $ligues_events[$item['league_name']][$key] = $item['event_name'];
}
```

And output it:

```
foreach ($ligues_events as $ligue_name => $events) {
    echo $ligue_name;
    foreach ($events as $event) {
        echo $event;
    }
}
```

[wpdb::get_results](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_results/)

[Hardcoded example](http://tpcg.io/KPm5euAy)